# Inserting a list into an array as a row in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I didn't see this anywhere as a Java question, so I'm askin' it.

I know how to convert a list to an array, when I'm converting the thing wholesale. But what I'm trying to do do is have a list that I create, then randomize. I then want to insert that list as the "bottom" row of a new array, because ultimately I'm making a game. A simplified version of what I'm talking about is here:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();

// populate the list
matchList.add("Apple");
matchList.add("Table");
matchList.add("Penny");
```

If I wanted to print this list I could:
    //System.out.println("Initial collection: "+matchList);

```
// Now I shuffle the list
Collections.shuffle(matchList);
```

I could print this new list, too:
    // System.out.println("Final collection after shuffle: "+matchList);

What I want to wind up with is an array that looks like this:

```
 String[][]  newBoard  =  {  
  {  "00000", "00000", "00000", },
  {  "00000", "00000", "00000", },
  {  "Apple", "Table", "Penny", },
  };
```

Except that's all manual, and what I wasn is that last row to be whatever the randomized ones I wound up with were. Eventually, I'll need to be able to move each one of them upwards, and possible swap their positions, dependent on other actions in the game. But right now I'm stuck on the very basics of that.

I also am going to ultimately want to make it display to the user as:

```
  00000 00000 00000
  00000 00000 00000
  XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX
```

(And in subsequent iterations,

```
  00000 00000 00000
  00000 XXXXX 00000
  XXXXX 00000 XXXXX,
```

etc.)

That is, have the variable items hidden behind Xs. I know I'll need a private class or something for that, but I haven't gotten there yet because right now I'm just stuck on the "randomize, then make board" part.

Comment: Did `Stack` not help?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add the elements into the array using the List.get(index) method.

```
 String[][]  newBoard  =  {  
{  "00000", "00000", "00000", }, 
{  "00000", "00000", "00000", }, 
{  matchList.get(0), matchList.get(1), matchList.get(2), }, 
};
```